# Single fragment in xml gives preview error: "Cyclic include, not valid"

Tags: android, eclipse, graphical-layout-editor

When I try to show an android xml file in the graphical layout in Eclipse I get this message:  pick preview layout from the Fragment Layout context menu. I follow the instruction  by right clicking the layout --> Fragment Layout --> Choose layout. However, when I try to choose my layout (the file that of some reason can't be displayed) I get this error: "Cyclic include, not valid". I can choose all other layouts such as androids predefined list_content.

What am I doing wrong?

Here is my xml:

```
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/example_id"
    android:name="com.example.test.MainFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

and here is my java:

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
}
```

Here is a print screen:

[image: Print screen of "Cyclic include, not valid" error]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After getting pointed in the right direction by @MiStr in the comments to his answer I understood that the reason I got the cyclic include error were quite obvious. I was trying to set the preview layout of the fragment to a view that contained the fragment. The preview layout should be the root layout of the fragment, not the fragment itself... The root layout is the layout that is returned by the fragments `onCreateView()` method. More info here http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#Creating

ListFragment automatically creates a root layout so that you don't have to override the onCreateView() method. Eclipse (I don't know about android studio) should automatically preview a sample list however for ListFragment.

Answer (score 1):

You should include a name attribute in the fragment XML item.. such as:

```
android:name="com.example.news.ArticleListFragment"
```

...where "ArticleListFragment" is the Fragment class that you want to use. Full snippet is:

```
<fragment android:name="com.example.news.ArticleListFragment"
            android:id="@+id/list"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

See also: [Fragments](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html), and [Creating a Fragment](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/creating.html).

Comment: True. However it doesn't solve the problem. Any other suggestions? I updated the code in the questions with the name attribute.

Comment: What is the entirety of your file? Does it have the standard heading: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>... also, is it within a layout container?

Comment: It seems that there is a cyclical reference that needs to be cleared up.. Also, the class that references this XML layout file should not be the one given in the "name" attribute.

Comment: Provide the layout file for MainFragment as well.. What does MainFragment include for its layout...

Comment: True! After you pointed me in the right direction I understood that I was trying to set the preview layout of the fragment to a view that contained the fragment which of course resulted in the cyclic include error.

Comment: That is the entirety of my test file. When I don't use a layout container I just get the text "Text" and a gray background no matter which preview layout I chooses. Is that a limitation of the graphical-layout-editor?

Comment: I suppose it is a limitation.. I assume you're using Android Studio? It is still a "beta" product, but I use it as well.

Comment: Nope, here I'm actually using Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

only import android.app.Fragment; can get the preview!
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment; can't get preview!